# Marking email as unread issue in Outlook app

Tags: outlook, oneplus-5, oneplus-x, oneplus-5t

If I want to mark an email as unread in my Outlook app, I have to do it twice, because after the first time it changes back to the 'read' status (after a few seconds).

The problems occurs on a OnePlus 5T phone running Android 8.0.0 and I haven't found anyone else online reporting this small but annoying issue. It looks like a bug to me, but maybe someone else has encountered this as well or has some ideas to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried on any PC or online: to mark an e-mail as unread? If this malfunction shows there too it's possibly your e-mail provider has the problem.

Comment: @BálintBabics Yes, I have. On my computer this problem does not occur, so I still don't have a clue where the issue comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook's support team helped me.
They suggested to delete my account, subsequently clear the application's cache and then to add my account again.

Update: This seemed to work in the very beginning, but the issue actually persists.

Update2: The Outlook development team is investigating the matter. We'll have to wait for an update.

Update3: The issue is resolved since some time, presumably because Outlook fixed this bug and updated the app.